# How to open about:blank IE tab from command line?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, command-line

```
start iexplore.exe www.[SITE1].com
"PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 2000 >NUL
start SITE2
```

That's what I'm doing and normally it would open `SITE1` and then tab to open a `SITE2` if `SITE2` were not `about:blank`. However, the problem is that `about:blank` does not have the same `www.[SITE].com` format and, therefore, is not opened.

I want to open `PAGE1` then open `about:blank`.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution was to SendKeys via visual basic script.

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 5 * 1000
WshShell.SendKeys("^(t)")
```